# How to resolve a missing libproxy1 dependency on Wily

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 15.10, vpn

I'm installing the Citrix VPN client using the installer `nsgclient.deb` on Wily and I get the error `Dependency is not satisfiable: libproxy1`. I tried apt-get with this result:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libproxy1
...
Package libproxy1 is not available, but is referred to by another      package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libproxy1v5:i386 libproxy1v5

E: Package 'libproxy1' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. Can I just create a link to the `libproxy1v5` file? If so i'm not sure how to.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libproxy1v5
Reading package lists... Done
Reading state information... Done
libproxy1v5 is already the newest version.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libproxy1

**UPDATE 1** Hi @A.B. I'm trying your solution. The dpkg gives me this:

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.debdpkg: regarding libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb containing libproxy1:amd64:
 libproxy1v5:amd64 conflicts with libproxy1
  libproxy1:amd64 (version 0.4.11-0ubuntu4) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libproxy1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

**UPDATE 2** I setup a 14.04 on VirutalBox and was able to install `nsgclient.deb` on that and successfully vpn to our network. Guess I can downgrade/reinstall my OS but would be nice if I could get it working on the current 15.10 install.

Answer (score 1):

The package `libproxy1` isn't `libproxy1v5`. The problem, `libproxy1` was replaced in Wily with `libproxy1v5`. But you can install the Trusty `libproxy1` in parallel. Open a terminal and run:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

---

Unusual, but also possible to get updates for this package, add the Trusty (LTS) repository to your `sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Hi AB i thought i'd try upgrading to 16.04 and have run into the same issue again. I have tried adding trusty main to my sources.list and attempted the libproxy1_0.4.11...deb again with similar results as when i tried it with 15.10. Unfortunately this is not done in a vm like before so not sure if i want to go through a downgrade like before.